# Cannot acces Quorum IBFT remote node

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum

I managed to setup Quorum IBFT nodes on my MacOS. So far it works - deploying smart contracts, submitting transactions and etc using Metamask using RPC URL localhost:22000- as expected on the local machine (IP 192.168.0.102).

However, on other machine (different IP address) I got error in Metamask "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?" when I tried to add a new network the RPC URL of http://192.168.0.102:22000.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you enabled cors on your geth node?
Also take a look at: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91196/could-not-fetch-chain-id-is-your-rpc-url-correct

Comment: Hi Sandhu, with --rpccorsdomain yes I did!