# Getting error "Could not fetch chain ID. Is your RPC URL correct?" in metamask while trying to add Anvil running on wsl

Tags: metamask, wallets, vscode, anvil, local-blockchain

I was trying to add the Anvil to add on metamask, which was running in WSL.

[image: metamask error]

In my VScode the Anvil is running:
[image: Anvil]

What is causing the problem here ? How to fix the problem ?

Comment: This might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/91196/could-not-fetch-chain-id-is-your-rpc-url-correct.